# cannot have an overloaded operator called

Tags: c++, operators

I try to have an operator== called from a derived class

but if i use base class pointers, it does not work, although the objects are created as derived classes

```
class A 
{
public:
    bool operator==(const A & other)
    {
        cout << "this should never been called" << endl;
        return this==&other;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    bool operator==(const A & other)
    {
        cout << "this should be called instead" << endl;
        return this==&other;
    }
};

void process(A _b1,A _b2)
{
    if(_b1==_b2)
    {
       cout << "here" << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
   B b1;
   B b2;

   process(b1,b2);
}
```

although the operators overload have the same signature, i dont get it

plz help me out

thx

Comment: for some reason the Hello at the beginning of my thread don't show up

so.. Hello :-)

Comment: It does not really make sense to compare the memory address in the equality operator. You can just do that by default without implementing operator==.

Comment: By passing b1 and b2 to process they are implicitly casted to type A (the type of the arguments of process).

Comment: You need to deal with the slicing problem *and* use the `virtual` keyword. Note that a virtual `==` operator that actually makes any sense is extremely tricky, as are all other "binary" operators.

Comment: no slicing here, besides it works with other OO languages but i a m not sure if it is my code wich is wrong or acpp limitation

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. You *are* encountering slicing problems here.

Comment: ok but even c++ should call the most specialised operator

Comment: i added virtual to the A class operator but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the bool operator==() in the class A should be `virtual`.
Like:

```
class A 
{
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const A& other) { ... }
};
```

That means that even if you refer to a class A, it can be treated as B, if that is what it really is.

Second, you make a copy of your B instances to A instances.
That is a conversion you do not want.
Instead you should pass them "by reference".
Like this:

```
void process(A& _b1,A& _b2)
{
    ...
}
```

That way, when they are actually processed, they still refer to the original objects, which are of class B.

Comment: YESSS the reference trick did it !!
thx mate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `void process(A _b1,A _b2)`, it makes an implicit conversion/upcasting of the B class in A class, so it is called the A operator==, you should change your code to support polymorphism:

```
class A 
{
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const A & other)
    {
        cout << "this should never been called" << endl;
        return this==&other;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const A & other)
    {
        cout << "this should be called instead" << endl;
        return this==&other;
    }
};

void process(A& _b1,A& _b2)
{
    if(_b1==_b2)
    {
       cout << "here" << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
   B b1;
   B b2;

   process(b1,b2);
}
```

Ciao
Angelo